# selection sort for array of objects

Tags: c++, class, sorting, selection-sort

Iam trying to make selection sort for array of objects considering i have Data class

I want to sort them depending on the id attribute of the object

```
class Data
{
public:
    string name;
    int id;
};

    }
int main()
{
    Data m[3];
    m[0].id = 5;
    m[1].id = 4;
    m[2].id = 8;
    selsort(m, 3);
    cout << m[0].id;
};
```

I cannot understand what is wrong  nothing happens to the array ?

Comment: Please see https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. Now is a good time to learn how to debug your own programs.

Comment: As to the logic of the function ? i mean i debug the program but what about the sorting ? the `cout` result is 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
if ((mry[min].id < mry[j].id) < 0)
```

to:

```
if ((mry[min].id > mry[j].id) )
```

You are finding the minimum index, so you have to swap if you find an index with a value that is lesser than the current minimum.

A better way to accomplish this is to make your function take in another parameter called a comparator function which tells the function how to compare; that way you can reuse your function if you change to mind and what to sort it by another parameter.

```
void selsort(Data mry[], int n, std::function<int(Data, Data)> cmp) // mry[] is the object array, n is the 
                                     // number of objects in the array
    {
        int pass, j, min;
        Data temp;
        for (pass = 0; pass <= n - 2; pass++)  // passes
        {
            min = pass;
            for (j = pass + 1; j < n; j++)  // in each pass
                if (cmp(mry[min], mry[j]) > 0)
                    min = j;
            temp = mry[min];
            mry[min] = mry[pass];
            mry[pass] = temp;
        }

    }
```

And you can define a compare by `id` function:

```
int compare_by_id(Data d1, Data d2) 
{
    return d1.id - d2.id;
}
```

Call your function like this:

```
selsort(array, size, compare_by_id);
```

The best part is you can define your own function that can compare the elements as you want and that way your `selsort()` is versatile.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is a typo in the function declaration

```
void selsort(media mry[], int n)
             ^^^^^
```

I think you mean

```
void selsort( Data mry[], int n)
              ^^^^
```

This if statement

```
if ((mry[min].id < mry[j].id) < 0)
```

does not make sense.

You should write

```
if ( mry[min].id < mry[j].id )
```

Or if you want to sort in the ascending order then write the condition like

```
if ( mry[j].id < mry[min].id )
```